# Excel 2013 - Multiple Countifs

Tags: microsoft-excel-2013, countif

I've been progressing through a series of countifs but have come stuck. I need to count the number of "yes" each week, where there was not "Yes" in the previous weeks, but count the "Yes" if there was "No" in between the "Yes". For example Week 4 should count "yes" 3 times, because Store A,C & G had "No" in the previous week, but Stores B & H had no visit, with "Yes" recorded on the previous visit.

Currently using this convoluted formula, which returns 0:

```
=COUNTIFS(C$3:C$11,"<>"&$N$12,
          D$3:D$11,"<>"&$N$12,
          E$3:E$11,"<>"&$N$12,
          F$3:F$11,$N$12)
```

Row 12 are the counts I should have.

Here is my example.
[image]

Comment: A `PivotTable` might help as I think it can do this type of totaling without the formulae.

Comment: @miltonb if you know of a way to have a pivot table do this, please post it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I would set up a similar chart below your original chart and instead of using countifs, replace your NO and YES with 1 and 0 when your conditions are met. Using an `IF(AND` formula

```
    1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10
A   0   1   0   1   0   0   0   1   0   0
B   0   1   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   1
C   1   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0
D   0   0   1   0   0   0   1   0   1   0
E   1   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   1   0
F   1   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0
G   0   1   0   1   0   0   1   0   0   0
H   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0
I   1   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   1   0
    4   4   1   3   2   1   3   1   4   1
```

For example for week 2 (week 1 will only have 1 condition) I would start with this formula -

```
=IF(AND(B2="NO",C2="YES"),1,0)
```

I would drag this formula down and copy across. At the bottom sum your 1 and 0 for the week to get your total for the conditions. Week 4 = 3!